# Scale multiple tables by the same factor to fit widest table

Tags: tables, scaling

This might be asking a *lot*, but I would love to have a way to automatically scale multiple tables with similar content by the same factor such that the widest table fits to a particular width (e.g., textwidth), without having to manually manage the scale factor.

---

As an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}


\newlength{\cell}
\setlength{\cell}{3cm}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Wide}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} \\
            \midrule
            \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} \\
            \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} \\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}

\setlength{\cell}{4cm}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Wider}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} \\
            \midrule
            \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} \\
            \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}

\setlength{\cell}{5cm}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Widest}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} \\
            \midrule
            \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} \\
            \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} & \rule{\cell}{1ex} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

All tables fit within `\textwidth` using `resizebox`. But I would like to automatically scale all by the same factor such that the widest table fits `\textwidth`. The goal is for all tables to fit the page but also to have a consistent appearance (in terms of font sizes, etc.).

Comment: Because of the issue regarding changing font sizes whan using `resizebox` on a table, I'd suggest to not use that method. Instead you can manually change the font site (suing `\small`...), or adjust the `\tabcolsep`. Depending on the table you could also introduce linebreaks in the contents of the cells. `tabularx` or `tabular*` might also come in handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, *please*, don't do this. Please :-)

If the table is too large you should change the font size or rearrange the table to make it fit. Even if you scale all the tables by the same amount, the best you can get is a *consistent inconsistency*.

However, should you insist on this, here's a `\ScaleorResize` command, which takes two arguments: `#1`, the width of the widest thing and `#2`, a thing. The command typesets the thing and steals its scale factor from `\resizebox` (which is a `\scalebox` in disguise). The command then checks that stolen scale factor against the largest known scale factor, conveniently called `\PleaseDontSF` (`SF` stands for Scale Factor :-). If that scale factor is larger, `\PleaseDontSF` is updated and the thing is typeset. Otherwise the thing is rescaled to `\PleaseDontSF`. Since the widest thing might happen at the end of the document, `\PleaseDontSF` is saved to the `.aux` file to be updated in the next LaTeX run, so you need at least two runs to ensure that the scaling is <s>right</s> less wrong.

Here it goes. Put everything from `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in your document and replace all `\resizebox{<something>}{!}` by `\ScaleorResize{<something>}`. I put your table in a command, for brevity, but in your document you don't need that:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\edef\scalefactor{\strip@pt\maxdimen}
\edef\PleaseDontSF{\strip@pt\maxdimen}
\edef\PleaseDontCHK{\strip@pt\maxdimen}
\let\graphicx@Gscale@box\Gscale@box
\long\def\Gscale@box#1{%
  \xdef\scalefactor{#1}%
  \graphicx@Gscale@box{#1}}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\write\@auxout
    {\gdef\noexpand\PleaseDontSF{\PleaseDontCHK}}}%
\newsavebox\@weirdbox@a
\newsavebox\@weirdbox@b
\protected\long\def\ScaleorResize#1#2{%
  \sbox\@weirdbox@a{#2}%
  \sbox\@weirdbox@b{\resizebox{#1}{!}{\usebox\@weirdbox@a}}%
  \ifdim\scalefactor\p@<\PleaseDontCHK\p@
    \xdef\PleaseDontCHK{\scalefactor}%
  \fi
  \ifdim\scalefactor\p@<\PleaseDontSF\p@
    \xdef\PleaseDontSF{\scalefactor}%
    \usebox\@weirdbox@b
  \else
    \scalebox{\PleaseDontSF}{\usebox\@weirdbox@a}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\def\weirdtable#1{%
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    \toprule
      \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} & \textbf{Column 3} \\
    \midrule
      \rule{#1}{1ex} & \rule{#1}{1ex} & \rule{#1}{1ex} \\
      \rule{#1}{1ex} & \rule{#1}{1ex} & \rule{#1}{1ex} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Wide}
  \centering
  \ScaleorResize{\textwidth}{\weirdtable{3cm}}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Wider}
  \centering
  \ScaleorResize{\textwidth}{\weirdtable{4cm}}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Widest}
  \centering
  \ScaleorResize{\textwidth}{\weirdtable{5cm}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Behold:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm heading off to do this now. :)

Comment: @badroit You've been warned ;-)